# Removing a DOM element of a mounted Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project that incorporates React Component into a NON-react environment.

The project uses Backbone and we're slowly migrating some parts of the website to React.

My question:
Will removing a DOM node (by backbone/jquery) release the memory associated with the React component?
The docs clearly state that you must manage your own mounting/un-mounting, however I'm wondering if simply removing the DOM will clean up the memory for me, or do I need to worry about memory leaks in a long-lived page?

an example usecase is navigating away(using our backbone router) and re-rendering the page, this removes all previous nodes and builds new html - so what happens to all the mounted react components?

Edit:
To be clear, I'm not modifying a rendered component with jQuery.

```
class App extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return (<div>Amazing</div>);
   }
}



//extreme use case, render a component, remove the DOM node, create a new DOM node
setInterval(function(){
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App),document.getElementById('app'));
    $('#app').remove();
    $('body').append($('<div id="app">'));
},250)
```

Edit : 
After investigating the issue,  you must detect removed nodes using MutationObserver and unmount them, if you don't the nodes will continue to be rendered in memory.
I wrote a full description here :

https://medium.com/@patrick.tolosa/backbone-router-with-react-components-13791727a351

Comment: log componentWillUnmount and there's the answer

Comment: I logged it, it's not running :) but my question is about memory allocation and not just the lifecycle method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove a DOM node that React rendered by directly manipulating the DOM, React will **not know** of these changes. If the React component is then re-rendered, the previously removed DOM node will reappear because it still exists in Reacts virtual DOM.

You should avoid manipulating the parts of the DOM which React has created. This may cause unwanted behavior in your application.

For example, removing a DOM node which React rendered may throw the following exception on re-render:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

or some other *DOMException*.

---

Here's what the [**official documentation**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#integrating-with-dom-manipulation-plugins) says about updating the DOM:

> React is unaware of changes made to the DOM outside of React. It
>   determines updates based on its own internal representation, and if
>   the same DOM nodes are manipulated by another library, React gets
>   confused and has no way to recover.
>
> This does not mean it is impossible or even necessarily difficult to
>   combine React with other ways of affecting the DOM, you just have to
>   be mindful of what each are doing.
>
> The easiest way to avoid conflicts is to prevent the React component
>   from updating. You can do this by rendering elements that React has no
>   reason to update, like an empty `<div />`.

It goes on with an example integration of React with jQuery, [**here**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#how-to-approach-the-problem).

Finally, I suggest further reading on the *Virtual DOM*. The official documentation doesn't seem to say much about it, but search online and you'll find a plethora of guides; like [this one](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-virtual-dom).

Comment: I did read those docs, but they avoid the exact question at hand. The issue is not about changing a React Component, but removing the `root node` all together. I've updated my question to reflect this as I think it was unclear.

Comment: @Patrick, the answer is the same. React is still "running" even if you remove the root node. So while removing it isn't "ideal", it shouldn't be a problem if you remove the node and re-insert it. Just know that React will make any updates as if it was never removed. In other words, the whole application state will remain. The only issue will be if React tries to do something while the root node is removed. Hope this answers your question? :)

Comment: Thanks ! that's as far as I suspected, I guess I'll have to profile just a bit deeper to ensure no crazy memory leaks occur.